# Spring JMS Integration with Apache Pulsar

Tags: spring-jms, apache-pulsar

Our current code is that we use MQ to receive messages from upstream application. JMS will consume messages from MQ and inserts into database.

The requirement is that instead of MQ we need to use Apache Pulsar now. Is it possible to use Apache pulsar to connect with JMS. If so, do we have any Apache Pulsar connection factory and properties to connect to JMS similar to IBM MQ connection to JMS which I posted below:

```xml
<bean id="NEPrimaryJmsConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
    <property name="hostName" value="${CSGW_NE_PRIMARY_HOST_NAME}" />
    <property name="port" value="${CSGW_NE_PRIMARY_PORT_NO}" />
    <property name="queueManager" value="${CSGW_NE_PRIMARY_QUEUE_MANAGER}" />
    <property name="transportType" value="1" />
</bean>
<bean id="NEPrimaryJmsDestination" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="${CSGW_NE_PRIMARY_QUEUE_NAME}" />
</bean>
<bean id="NEPrimaryConnectionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="NEPrimaryJmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="NEPrimaryJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="NEPrimaryConnectionFactory" />
    <property name="defaultDestination" ref="NEPrimaryJmsDestination" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is one open source binding for Apache Pulsar and JMS.
https://github.com/datastax/pulsar-jms

There is also a example to use Spring JMS in the repository

I am one of the maintainers.
Feel free to open issues on the GH issues tab in case you have problems.

Comment: The answer would be much improved with an example Spring configuration mimicking what the OP already has. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), "Links to other websites should always be _helpful_, but avoid making it _necessary_ to click on them as much as possible."

Answer (score -2):

There is no reference to JMS in the [Pulsar documentation](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/). From this I can only conclude that there is no JMS client implementation for Pulsar which means you won't be able to integrate with Pulsar via Spring JMS like you did with IBM MQ.

Comment: Pulsar is an open-source project and has an ecosystem outside of the official project, so you can't make conclusions based on the project documentation. In fact, there is a JMS project for Pulsar: https://github.com/datastax/pulsar-jms

Comment: Good to know, Chris. Thanks for the info! For what it's worth, as an Apache committer myself I'm aware that Pulsar is open source. I did a search for "apache pulsar jms" but I didn't see anything immediately relevant. On closer inspection I see now that I didn't scroll down far enough to see the datastax link.